# OpenTSDB filter tags exclude specific tag

Tags: opentsdb

Is it possible to query for all possible values but exclude a specific value from search?

For example `m=sum:rate:proc.stat.cpu{host=foo,type=*?!user}` meaning all values for `type` but exclude `user` value. Or something like `m=sum:rate:proc.stat.cpu{host=foo,type=*, type=!user}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, as of OpenTSDB 1.1.0 this isn't currently supported.  There is no fundamental reason why it wouldn't be supported, it's just that this isn't implemented yet.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I strongly consider joining OpenTSDB group and maybe help you guys as much as I can.

Answer (score 3):

As an update, this is now supported in OpenTSDB versions 2.X using the **not_literal_or** filter.
You can do `m=sum:rate:proc.stat.cpu{host=foo,type=not_literal_or(user)}`

Comment: Yup, that's right. Adding a link to TSD docs as well: http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/query/filters.html#built-in-2-x-filters